# Group by in Matrix Model List in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, list

I Have Matrix Model Class. It has enumerable list. in my list available hotels repeating, so, I need to have another list which have to be unique hotels, Need to group by HotelCode. Can anyone please help me on this??

```
public  class JsonMatrixModel
    {
        public class Result
        {

            public string responseId { get; set; }
            public string searchId { get; set; }
            public int totalFound { get; set; }
            public List<availableHotels> availableHotels { get; set; }
        }

        public class availableHotels
        {
            public string processId { get; set; }
            public string hotelCode { get; set; }
            public string availabilityStatus { get; set; }

            public double totalPrice { get; set; }
            public double totalTax { get; set; }

            public double totalSalePrice { get; set; }

            public string currency { get; set; }

            public string boardType { get; set; }
            public List<rooms> rooms { get; set; }



        }

        public class rooms
        {
            public string roomCategory { get; set; }
            public List<paxes> paxes { get; set; }
            public double totalRoomRate { get; set; }
            public List<ratesPerNight> ratesPerNight { get; set; }
        }

        public class paxes
        {
            public string paxType { get; set; }
            public int age { get; set; }


        }

        public class ratesPerNight
        {
            public string date { get; set; }
            public double amount { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

---

```
     requestUrl = apiURL + query;

            var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string tstobj;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                tstobj = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

 List<JsonMatrixModel.Result> ddd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonMatrixModel.Result>>("[" + tstobj + "]");
```

Comment: Are you sure your definition for JsonMatrixModel is correct, it only contains sub classes, which is a bit odd.  If you want to organise you classes then put them in a namespace.  If you want to encapsulate your data in a single class then create properties that are instances of those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, JsonMatrixModel.availableHotels>> quer =
      from ff in ddd
      from ss in ff.availableHotels
      group ss by ss.hotelCode;
```